# finding isothermal coordinates uniformly

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

It's a well-known but difficult theorem that any $C^2$ surface in $R^3$ with parameter domain the unit disk can be put into isothermal parameters.  The Wikipedia article on isothermal coordinates references several proofs (none of which I can access immediately).  Suppose given a family of surfaces $X^t$ such that the map $t \mapsto X^t$ is continuous from some interval of $t$ values to $C^n(D,R^3)$.  Then can we find surfaces $Y^t$ such that $Y^t$ gives isothermal parameters for $X^t$ and the map $t \mapsto Y^t$ is continuous into $C^n(D,R^3)$?

It looks like this might follow if we know (a) the isothermal parameters are solutions of some differential equation and (b) solutions of that differential equation depend continuously in the $C^n$ metric on parameters.   That proof promises to involve checking a lot of details in two complicated proofs and will look like hand-waving.   So perhaps this is stated somewhere in the literature?

Comment: Do you need some boundedness conditions on the "$C^2$ surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with parameter domain the unit disk" you permit?  Otherwise, you might end up with surfaces like the plane, which cannot be put into global isothermal co-ordinates with domain the disc (although of course it admits local isothermal co-ordinates).

Answer (score 4):

Choose $o^t\in X^t$ so that $t\mapsto o^t$ is smooth
and yet choose a famity of unit vectors $u^t\in T_{o^t}X^t$, so that $t\mapsto u^t$ is smooth.

Parametrize $X^t$ isothermaly by unit disc $f^t:D\to X^t$ in such a way that $f^t(0)=o^t$ and $(d_0f^t)(1)$ is proportional to $u^t$.
Such a parametrization is unique.
[The later follows since conformal diffeomorphism $h:D\to D$ such that $h(0)=0$ and $h'(0)\in\mathbb R_+$ has to be identity.]

It follows that $t\mapsto f^t$ is continuous;
otherwise different partial limits would give different isothermal coordinate with chousen origin and real direction.

With a bit more work, one can show that $t\mapsto f^t$ is smooth.

Comment: This seems like an excellent idea, and a big improvement over trying to check the detailed proofs.  As soon as I can work out the details I will accept your answer.

Comment: I tried to work out the details.  There is a gap, though.  Suppose we have a sequence of isothermal parametrizations $Y^{t_n}$ that are bounded in $C^n$ norm away from $X^0$.  Now we need to argue by compactness that some subsequence converges.  For that we need a uniform bound on the isothermal parametrizations $Y^t$.   Where will we get a bound on the $C^n$ norms of the $Y^t$?

Comment: The isothermal coordinate is a solution of some elliptic PDE with coefficients taken from the first fundamental form. Such solutions are known to be uniformly smooth in a compact subdomain. From this you should get $C^\infty$ case. For $C^n$ you have to be more careful, the first fundamental form is in class $C^{n-1}$, but if I remember right solution of elliptic equation with such coefficient should be $C^n$... (It was a while since I study this stuff.)

Comment: Now I have another difficulty with your answer. Let's check the uniqueness.  Suppose $W$ and $V$  are two different isothermal parametrizations of $X$ (taking 0 to the same point and having the same x-derivative at 0).   Then if I understand you, you want to 
define $\varphi:= W^{-1} V$ and say that $\varphi$ is a conformal mapping of the disk, fixing 0 and with $\varphi_x(0) = 1$, 
and therefore $\varphi$ is the identity.   Nice, but, the domain of $W^{-1}$ is a geometric surface, so how do I define it if $W$ is not one-one?   It seems this will only work to get LOCAL isothermal coordinates.

Comment: @Michael Beeson:  Since $W$ and $V$ are two different parametrizations of $X$, we can write $V=W\circ\varphi$, for some self-diffeomorphism $\varphi$ of the disc.  Since $W$ and $V$ are both conformal, we know that $\varphi$ must be locally conformal, hence conformal.